# ElasticSearch won't allow for CORS even though its disabled

Tags: node.js, reactjs, elasticsearch

I'm running ElasticSearch 6.6.1 on kubernetes together with a few NodeJS containers. I'm having no problem uploading to elasticsearch through NodeJS, but I can't query it.

My `elasticsearch.yml`:

```
node.data: ${NODE_DATA:true}
node.master: ${NODE_MASTER:true}
node.ingest: ${NODE_INGEST:true}
node.name: ${HOSTNAME}

network.host: 0.0.0.0
# see https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/3595
bootstrap.memory_lock: ${BOOTSTRAP_MEMORY_LOCK:false}

discovery:
  zen:
    ping.unicast.hosts: ${DISCOVERY_SERVICE:}
    minimum_master_nodes: ${MINIMUM_MASTER_NODES:2}

# see https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-definitive-guide/pull/679
processors: ${PROCESSORS:}

# avoid split-brain w/ a minimum consensus of two masters plus a data node
gateway.expected_master_nodes: ${EXPECTED_MASTER_NODES:2}
gateway.expected_data_nodes: ${EXPECTED_DATA_NODES:1}
gateway.recover_after_time: ${RECOVER_AFTER_TIME:5m}
gateway.recover_after_master_nodes: ${RECOVER_AFTER_MASTER_NODES:2}
gateway.recover_after_data_nodes: ${RECOVER_AFTER_DATA_NODES:1}
http.cors.enabled : true
http.cors.allow-origin: "*"
http.cors.allow-methods: OPTIONS, HEAD, GET, POST, PUT, DELETE
http.cors.allow-headers: X-Requested-With, X-Auth-Token, Content-Type, Content-Length, Authorization, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Accept
```

And it seems to read `elasticsearch.yml` correctly, because curling the address gives

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
access-control-allow-origin: *
content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
content-length: 518

{
  "name" : "elasticsearch-client-65459787c-mkjws",
...
```

Here's my `ReactiveBase` component:

```
    app="amalfi/default2"
    url="http://elasticsearch-client:9200"
    headers={{
         'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }}
>
```

The elasticsearch service is called `elasticsearch-client`.

When trying to access it over http (the website uses https) I'm getting `This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.`
But when using HTTPS I'm getting `"Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at mysite.com"`, but it should allow connections from everywhere because of `http.cors.allow-origin: "*"`, right?

The wierd thing is that I'm having to problem uploading to ElasticSearch, but querying it is a bit tricky...

I've tried setting the exact address as `http.cors.allow-origin: https://my-address-here.com` but it gave the error...
I've also tried `https.cors.allow-origin: /https?:\/\/localhost(:[0-9]+)?/` with the same results.

Comment: I've found the following on elasticsearch's website. Can you try something like this?

`http.cors.allow-origin
 

Which origins to allow. Defaults to no origins allowed. If you prepend and append a / to the value, this will be treated as a regular expression, allowing you to support HTTP and HTTPs. for example using /https?:\/\/localhost(:[0-9]+)?/ would return the request header appropriately in both cases.`

Source: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-http.html

Comment: `http.cors.allow-origin: "*"` is in use atm. I've tried the other approach as well (`/https?:\/\/localhost(:[0-9]+)?/`) with the same results..

Comment: Are you using apache on your server?

Comment: It's hosted on Kubernetes.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not familiar with Kubernetes, but I've found [this](https://imti.co/kubernetes-ingress-nginx-cors/) on Kubernetes Ingress and CORS. Maybe that can help you?